# como ejecutar una sentencia mysql en php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

mi codigo es el siguiente y la funcion que quiero que realice esta en el exec

```
public function generar_periodo2()
{
  $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT af.id_af, af.tipo_dp, af.fecha_ad FROM activos_fijos af;";
  $data = $this->db->select($sql);
  foreach ($data as $af) {
  $tipo = ($af['tipo_dp'] == '1') ? "YEAR" : "MONTH";
    $this->db->exec("
      SET @intervalo = 1;
      UPDATE lineas_depreciacion ld SET ld.periodo = DATE_ADD({$af['fecha_ad']}, INTERVAL (@intervalo:= @intervalo+1) {$tipo})
        WHERE ld.id_activofijo = {$af['id_af']} AND ld.tipo_depre = '{$af['tipo_dp']}';
    ");
  }
}
```

porfavor si me pueden ayudar a ejecutar el SET @intervalo = 1;

Comment: El @intervalo siempre es 2?

Comment: no, debe ir sumando de 1 en 1

Comment: En tu código eso nunca va a pasar porque siempre inicia en 1. Intenta quitando el SET y el @intervalo + 1 debería ir dentro del foreach.

Comment: esa funcion que esta en el exec si se ejecuta correctamente en el mysql